# Svnserve path based authentication rejecting all connections

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnserve

So i have been using SVN over HTTP (Apache and WebDav) for a while now and i want to ditch apache and replace it with svnserve on my Raspberry Pi running the latest ArchLinux.

I started by enabling the svnserve service:
`systemctl enable svnserve`

Then, i added the necessary args to the command in the config file under `/etc/config.d/svnserve` which now contains the following

```
SVNSERVE_ARGS="-r /media/USB/repositories --config-file /media/USB/svnserve.conf"
SVNSERVE_USER="svn"
```

For the record `/media/USB` is a mount of `/dev/sda1` which is an NTFS storage device that is always plugged in.

I have about 70 repositories so it would be tedious to use the `conf/` directory inside each one of them to control access and from what i understood, i can do the same thing i was doing with DAV on Apache and have one configuration file to rule them all!

So i put under /media/USB all 3 files below:

**svnserve.conf**

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
authz-db = subversion.authz
password-db = subversion.passwd
realm = Subversion
```

**subversion.authz**

```
[/]
* = r
dany = rw
```

**subversion.passwd**

```
dany = some password hash
```

Now when i checkout a URL using `svn://TheCorrectIp/RepoName` using TortoiseSVN i get the following error:
`Error: No access allowed to this repository` and i don't even get a prompt to enter a user/pass combination.

Here is what i tried so far with no luck (restarting the service after each trial):

- Clear TortoiseSVN's password cache
- Copy all 3 config files under the repository's `conf/` directory (just to see if this was a path issue)
- Use absolute and relative paths in *authz-db* (relative to the repository's conf, as shown in the documentation, and relative to the svnserve.conf file)
- Create a fresh new repository and play with its conf directory alone

While fiddling with the svnserve.conf i notice something strange happening:

- If i comment out authz-db and password-db i still get the same problem
- If i change anon-access to read or write, and comment out everything else i am able to checkout the repository and i  don't get asked for any combination. If i leave the anon-access intact and put back either authz-db or password-db i am unable to checkout again
- Stopped the service and ran `svnserve -d --forground -r /media/USB/repositories --config-file /media/USB/svnserve.conf` to monitor console output while doing a checkout: Nothing shows on the console when i do a checkout.

I would really appreciate any feedback to what i might be doing wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, i finally figured it out, my passwd file was in the wrong format, it has to be like this

```
[users]
dany = unencrypted password
```

i will do so more searching to find out if you can actually encrypt the passwords